# PHP subfolder for each user "type"

Tags: php, security, session, directory

I have 3 subfolders in an `upload` folder. My code looks like this:

```
if(isset($_SESSION["u_type"]) && $_SESSION["u_type"] == 3) {
    $files = scandir($path."/3/") //$path is set somewhere above
    //...
}
```

Its working fine, but you can actually add a simple html tag, like `<img src="uploads/2/somathing.png/>`  and you can get any file from subdir 2 even if your "user type" is set to 3.

Is there a way to prevent it?

**I alredy tried:**

I'm using .htacces with `Options- Indexes` in it, but it only brevents direct listing of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way of doing this, it requires Apache webserver (for .htaccess files):

### Deny from all in uploads folder

Add this to your uploads folder in `.htaccess`:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
```

### Create a proxy php script `image.php`

Create a script named `image.php` and check your session in there:
(You might need to update this script to your requirements, this is a simple example which only supports jpeg).

```php
<?php

session_start();

//check session for permission here!

$userTypeId = 1; //change this to requirements

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
echo file_get_contents("uploads/" . $userTypeId . "/" . $_GET['image']);
```

### Now access images by accessing the proxy script

```
<img src="image.php?image=yourimage.jpg" />
```

### Update; you can chose to rewrite the `image.php?image=x.jpg`

You can chose to rewrite this path with `.htaccess` so it seems as if there is no proxy `.php` script at work.

```
RewriteRule ^/a_chosen_path_name/([^\.]+)\.(png|jpg|gif)$    /image.php?image=$1.$2 [NC,L]
```

After which you can use:

```
<img src="a_chosen_path_name/yourimage.jpg" />
```

Comment: I'll try it later and if it work, I'll accept as answer.

Comment: did it went well?

Comment: Yes, it was working fine.