# How to protect files in public folder in codeIgniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, file-access

how can I protect files in the public folder in the CodeIgniter framework to be not viewed by a user who is not logged in?
My public folder structure is as follows:

- public

  - logs

    - detailed_logs(public/logs/detailed_logs)
    - error_logs(public/logs/error_logs)
  - code

    - device.js(public/code/device.js)

I am able to access the files using the below URLs without logging in to the system.

1. `https://<ip_address>/logs/detailed_logs`
2. `https://<ip_address>/code/device.js`

Can someone help me in making it only accessible to the user who is logged in?

Comment: what auth system are you using? the easiest would be checking those links against a session

Comment: Move the non-public files _outside_ of your document root and rewrite requests for them through PHP to enforce access control.

Comment: A similar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69784648/1971062

Comment: Why do you have the logs in the public and not in Writable which is a protected address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the .htaccess file to the logs folder and allowed access only to the index.php file.
I also created PHP files for each log file and checked whether a user is logged in using the session variable and read the contents of the respective log files when verified the user is logged in.
Thanks for the help!